# How to stop page load in conditionals - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

i have some ASPX page. I have to check something in the url (in the server side). 
If the condition does not exist so i want to stop the page load and give some error message.

I didn't find somthing like: STOP, BREAK.

Comment: That's not how the web works - if you have a background polling task it should be running on a separate thread, and your HTTP request handling thread should exchange data with the polling thread (see "Producer-Consumer pattern").

Comment: To alter page life cycle, please read https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/394496/How-can-stop-Page-Load-on-Button-Click-Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could always throw an Error.

```
throw new Exception("Please use a specific Exception");
```

Or you could do a Response Redirect:

```
Response.Redirect("~/SomeErrorPage.aspx",true);
```

The important thing to note is the `true` Parameter here indicating that the current Response should be ended 'immediately'.